# How to keep an RGL plot on the screen when using Rscript?

Tags: r, rgl, rscript

I have a very simple .r file:

```
library("rgl")
par(ask=TRUE)

x=c(0.44,0.45)
y=c(0.2, 0.3)
z=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=length(x))

persp3d(x,y,z)
```

When I open a cmd screen and navigate to my R installation and try

```
Rscript P:\pathtoscript\example.r
```

I see the `persp3d` graph flash up really quickly and then disappear, even though my .r file contains the `par(ask=true)` command.

So my question is, how can I keep it up and play around with it, without it going away before I'm done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a more idiomatic way to do this type of thing, but you can just add `Sys.sleep(large_number_of_seconds)` to keep the R process alive. For example,

**script.R**

```
library("rgl")

x <- c(0.44, 0.45)
y <- c(0.2, 0.3)
z <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = length(x))

persp3d(x,y,z)
Sys.sleep(100000)
```

Also, the `ask` argument to `par` is only used in interactive sessions, which is why it was not working here.